# output before sleep using yii

Tags: php, yii

So I used the following code to output content before calling the php function sleep():

```
   ob_start();
   echo "hello world";
   ob_flush();
```

problem is that is not working using the yii framework. what should I do?

Comment: Add a `flush()` call as well. ob_flush cleans out the output buffering system within PHP, but does not actually do any output from php->outside world (aka the webserver).

Comment: that does not work :(
            ob_start();
       
            // $this->render('wait');
            
            echo "printing…<br />";
            
            ob_flush();
            flush();

Comment: I do not have an answer for you but I discovered that Yii uses `ob_start` and `ob_implicit_flush(false)` at many points of their code to output view elements.

Comment: Where are you using this code? A controller or a view? Like KahWee mentions above, views get buffered so they can be post-processed. If you post some more code, we can help better ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Oliver, your response helped me a lot.

I cleaned all levels in Yii2 to get it working

```
    for ($level = ob_get_level(); $level > 0; --$level) {
        if (!@ob_end_clean()) {
            ob_clean();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should test, if there is already an output buffer open by writing this before your code:

```
if( ob_get_level () > 0 )
    exit("That's why!");
```

My suggestion is, Yii or PHP itself has already opened an output buffer and you are just flushing it into the next level. If so, check the php.ini for `output_buffering` and of course the code before your code.